# C# 9.0 records - ToString not inherited

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, record-classes

consider:

```
// the ratioale for Wrapper is that it has a Json serializer that  
// serialize through Field (not included in this example)
record Wrapper<T> where T : notnull {
  protected Wrapper(T field) => Field = field; 
  protected Wrapper(Wrapper<T> wrapper) => Field = wrapper.Field;
  protected readonly T Field;
  public override string ToString() => Field.ToString() ?? "";
}

record MyRec : Wrapper<string> {
    public MyRec(string s) : base(s) {}
}

public static class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
      var r = new MyRec("hello");
      Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
  }
}
```

[sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

seems like base `ToString` is not inherinted and the compiler still autogenerates derived `Tostring`

Why is that ? is there any good way around it ?

Comment: You want ToString to return the string representing the wrapped object, right? Returning a serialized wrapper isn't usually going to be useful.

Comment: yes, I mentioned serialization to give the rationale for Wrapper

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you want an override in your Wrapper class to be the one invoked when you derive another class from that Wrapper, and what you're getting instead is the Object.ToString() invocation, is that right?

Comment: Just override it yourself, return base.ToString()

Comment: [C# 10 will add the ability to seal the ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#record-types-can-seal-tostring), so you can get what you wanted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a comment which has fixed this issue for me. Sean says if you add `sealed` to the method it stops the compiler from synthesizing the `ToString` method see below:

```
public sealed override string ToString() => Value;
```

Note that the ability to seal an override of `ToString` was [introduced in C# 10.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#record-types-can-seal-tostring)

Comment: This answer is way too underrated!

Comment: This was not possible in C# 9: https://anthonygiretti.com/2021/07/19/introducing-c-10-seal-overriden-tostring-method-on-records/ a comment below the article says: "[...] the point of this feature isn't really to prevent a user from overriding the method, but to prevent the compiler from doing so. Making the ToString method sealed was forbidden in C# 9 because the compiler always generated an override in a derived record. This made it impossible to implement ToString for a whole hierarchy of records. With this change, the compiler will no longer generate the override if the method is sealed."

Answer (score 12):

The `record` declaration supercedes the inherited `ToString()`. This is explained in the [What's New](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9) description:

> The compiler synthesizes two methods that support printed output: a ToString() override, and PrintMembers.

The fact that the base class (also a `record`) has a `ToString` override is not considered. Technically *all* types inherit `ToString()` from `object`, so the code generator for `record` types does not look at base types for an inherited override, otherwise a compiler-generated `ToString` would *never* be created.

(You could argue that a `ToString` in an inherited `record` type should be preserved, but that's not how the feature was designed).

But if the record type has an overridden `ToString()`, then the compiler does not generate one:

> If a record type has a method that matches the signature of any synthesized method, the compiler doesn't synthesize that method.

You could define a seemingly redundant override:

```
public override string ToString() => base.ToString();
```

This should prevent the compiler from auto-generating a `ToString` override due to the `record` declaration.

Comment: Thanks ! "Technically all types inherit ToString() from object, so the compiler does not look at base types for an inherited override" - no not for classes

Comment: @kofifus Yes - if you define a class it inherits the `ToString` method from `object` (or am I misunderstanding your statement?)

Comment: what I mean is that your statement above is not correct - for classes the compiler _does_ look at base types for an inherited override for ToString, so this is a difference between records and classes

Comment: By "compiler" I meant the code generator for `record` types. I clarified that in my answer.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your answer .. "Technically all types inherit ToString() from object, so the code generator for record types does not look at base types for an inherited override" - what is the A->B logic here ? yes all types inherit from object but that does not entail that the code generator for record should not look at base types as it does for ie GetHashCode .. is there anywhere in the docs where it specifies ToString is not inherited ? this is confusing to me

Comment: My point is that the code generator does not look at the parent `Wrapper` class and determine that since a `ToString` method is overridden there that it should not auto-generate one. Since this class was explicitly defined as  `record` the compiler auto-generates all `record` methods _that are not explicitly defined in that class_. If you want to "inherit" the custom method you have to explicitly do that in this case.

Comment: You might want to update your answer. It is now possible in C# 10 to seal a .ToString() override so the compiler no longer synthesizes .ToString() methods for inheriting records.