# Custom Equality check for C# 9 records

Tags: c#, record, equality, c#-9.0

From what I understand, records are actually classes that implement their own equality check in a way that your object is value-driven and not reference driven.

In short, for the `record Foo` that is implemented like so: `var foo = new Foo { Value = "foo" }` and `var bar = new Foo { Value = "foo" }`, the `foo == bar` expression will result in `True`, even though they have a different reference (`ReferenceEquals(foo, bar) // False`).

Now with records, even though that in [the article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#value-based-equality) posted in .Net Blog, it says:

> If you don’t like the default field-by-field comparison behaviour of
> the generated Equals override, you can write your own instead.

When I tried to place `public override bool Equals`, or `public override int GetHashCode`, or `public static bool operator ==`, and etc. I was getting `Member with the same signature is already declared` error, so I think that it is a restricted behaviour, which isn't the case with `struct` objects.

[Failing example](https://github.com/panosru/Playground/tree/7160550f3591dfb4b12c2722febed763d424980e/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS9Failing):

```cs
public sealed record SimpleVo
    : IEquatable<SimpleVo>
{
    public bool Equals(SimpleVo other) =>
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is SimpleVo other && Equals(other);

    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    public static bool operator ==(SimpleVo left, SimpleVo right) =>
        left.Equals(right);

    public static bool operator !=(SimpleVo left, SimpleVo right) =>
        !left.Equals(right);
}
```

Compiler result:

```
SimpleVo.cs(11,30): error CS0111: Type 'SimpleVo' already defines a member called 'Equals' with the same parameter types

SimpleVo.cs(17,37): error CS0111: Type 'SimpleVo' already defines a member called 'op_Equality' with the same parameter types

SimpleVo.cs(20,37): error CS0111: Type 'SimpleVo' already defines a member called 'op_Inequality' with the same parameter types
```

My main question here is what if we want to customise the way the equality checker works? I mean, I do understand that this beats the whole purpose of records, but on the other hand, equality checker is not the only feature that makes records cool to use.

One use case where someone would like to override the equality of records is because you could have an [attribute](https://github.com/panosru/Playground/blob/master/C%23/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS8/IgnoreMemberAttribute.cs) that would exclude a property from equality check. Take for example [this](https://github.com/panosru/Playground/blob/master/C%23/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS8/ValueObject.cs) `ValueObject` implementation.

Then if you extend this `ValueObject` abstract class like so:

```cs
public sealed class FullNameVo : ValueObject
{
    public FullNameVo(string name, string surname)
    {
        Name    = name;
        Surname = surname;
    }

    [IgnoreMember]
    public string Name { get; }

    public string Surname { get; }

    [IgnoreMember]
    public string FullName => $"{Name} {Surname}";
}
```

then you would get the following [results](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/wP9Fpm):

```cs
var user1 = new FullNameVo("John", "Doe");
var user2 = new FullNameVo("John", "Doe");
var user3 = new FullNameVo("Jane", "Doe");

Console.WriteLine(user1 == user2); // True
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(user1, user2)); // False
Console.WriteLine(user1 == user3); // True
Console.WriteLine(user1.Equals(user3)); // True
```

So far, in order to achieve *somehow* the above use case, I have implemented [an abstract record object](https://github.com/panosru/Playground/blob/master/C%23/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS9/ValueObject.cs) and utilise it like so:

```cs
public sealed record FullNameVo : ValueObject
{
    [IgnoreMember]
    public string Name;

    public string Surname;

    [IgnoreMember]
    public string FullName => $"{Name} {Surname}";
}
```

and the results look like this:

```cs
var user1 = new FullNameVo
{
    Name    = "John",
    Surname = "Doe"
};

var user2 = new FullNameVo
{
    Name    = "John",
    Surname = "Doe"
};

var user3 = user1 with { Name = "Jane" };

Console.WriteLine(user1 == user2); // True
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(user1, user2)); // False
Console.WriteLine(user1 == user3); // False
Console.WriteLine(user1.Equals(user3)); // False
Console.WriteLine(ValueObject.EqualityComparer.Equals(user1, user3)); // True
```

To conclude, I'm a bit puzzled, is restricting the override of equality methods of record objects an expected behaviour or is it because it is still in preview stage? If it is by design, would you implement the above behaviour in a different *(better)* way or you would just continue using classes?

`dotnet --version` output: `5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10`

Comment: What version of the C# 9 compiler are you using? I do note that C# 9.0 is still in preview (as far as I know) so some features may still not yet be available yet.

Comment: @Dai you are right pal! I missed mentioning that info! I will update my question now. FYI: 5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10

Comment: @Dai, to add, yes I understand that it is under development still, and I wouldn't ask the question if it wasn’t in RC1, so as a release candidate version I'm kind of puzzled if that is by design or it is just not implemented yet. :)

Comment: paste your actual Equals method. I just tried and it worked.

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev that is strange indeed. I will provide a failing example first thing in the morning!

Comment: @user2864740 I have refined my question. I also read about `EqualityContract`, but I couldn't find any example on how can I use it to override the default equality behaviour.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records — try just a “user-defined” method with the signature `public virtual bool Equals(FullNameVo? other)`. Most other forms ‘expected’ in a normal class type are forbidden — “It is an error if the override is declared explicitly” — from being specified manually defined as they will be synthesized (example given). Iff that works, also add the GetHashCode, as shown.

Comment: I suppose, remove the `virtual` or unseal the FullNamVo type as well: “The record type implements System.IEquatable<R> and includes a synthesized strongly-typed overload of Equals(R? other) where R is the record type. The method is public, and the method is virtual unless the record type is sealed. *The [bool Equals(R? r)] method can be declared explicitly. It is an error if the explicit declaration does not match the expected signature or accessibility, or the explicit declaration doesn't allow overriding it in a derived type and the record type is not sealed.*”

Comment: Basically, the goal is to prevent having to write *all* the methods, as might commonly be done with “generate equality members” *and* prevent errors in the process. Having the single Equals(R?) allows the *compiler synthesized* forms of ==, !=, Equals(object) and implicitly accepts Equals(R).

Comment: Out of curiosity can you do this with normal Classes (not Records)?

Comment: @JeremyThompson yes you can do it with classes and structs without any issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/apnl6x I only can't do it with records so far *(which could be my fault because records may require a different approach)*.

Comment: @user2864740, I read that page several times, it might be because my head is overloaded today or I might not understand the docs well. But even after reading that particular page several times, I still have the question on how then shall I override the equality since the docs don't state that you can't do it. Also since records implement `IEquatable<R>` does that mean that I don't have to re-implement it? Even with `public virtual bool Equals(SimpleVo other)` and without `sealed` keyword, I'm still getting a compiler error. If you have a working example, could you share it?

Comment: @JeremyThompson if you are interested you can check the implementation of `ValueObject` abstract class in C# 8 here: https://github.com/panosru/JustDemo/tree/master/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS8 That is how I have it so far, but I'm testing `record` types now so since .Net 5 is on RC1 already I feel that I can start testing C# 9 now and migrate to .Net 5 once it is released.

Comment: `public virtual bool Equals(SimpleVo other)` is not `public virtual bool Equals(SimpleVo? other)`. Also, per the information in the proposal, remove `virtual` if the type is `sealed`. Also, *remove* the explicit IEquatable. This is implicit in the record and synthesized, as shown in the synthesized examples.

Comment: @user2864740, yes you are correct, I missed the `?`. Based on docs though, it seems impossible to override `==` with `public static bool operator ==(SimpleVo left, SimpleVo right)` or `!=` custom operators, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: That’s correct per the current proposal. The point is that they *cannot be user-defined* as they are provided through rules deriving from Equals(R?).

Comment: @user2864740, that makes sense, and actually could be better, since if you can write your own implementation of `Equals` then you might not need to override `==` and `!=` operators *(as you used to do with classes and structs)*, or at least I can't find a case where I would need to override them. Usually, in my code, I just add nullability check inside my custom `==` operator. I'm now trying to write a working example and post it since it might help others as well.

Comment: So, did you figure out how to implement a custom equality check? I tried the solution from the accepted answer, but then I realized that I can't use the sealed keyword because I'm using a base record and deriving. So, for me, that solution won't work. Are you now using Records or are you still using classes? Do others you work with have an opinion on this issue? By the way, I just downloaded the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.11.3 and the Equals compiler errors you described are still present.

Comment: @BobBryan I'm sorry for my late reply, I was abroad. So far I'm mostly using Classes for value objects, but eventually, I will move to records. Could you check the working example here and see if it suits your needs? https://github.com/panosru/Playground/tree/master/C%23/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS9Working

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Per [the C#9 record proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records), the following *should compile*, even if not very useful without actual implementations..

```
// No explicit IEquatable<R> - this is synthesized!
public sealed record SimpleVo
{
    // Not virtual, as SimpleVo (R) is sealed.
    // Accepts SimpleVo? (R?), and not SimpleVo (R), as argument.
    public bool Equals(SimpleVo? other) =>
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    // Optional: warning generated if not supplied when Equals(R?) is user-defined.
    public int GetHashCode() =>
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();

    // No other “standard” equality members!
}
```

There are restrictions on the equality-related members as most of the code is synthesized. The proposal includes examples of the expected synthesized underlying type.

That is, given **just** a `Equals(R?)` the compiler creates a `==`, `!=`, and `Equals(object)`.
The methods that can be defined can be found by searching for “user-defined” in the proposal.

Attempting to override/define other equality methods or operators is *expected* to fail:

> It is an error if the override is declared explicitly.

The behavior is discussed in ‘Equality members’ and is summarized in the paragraph:

> The record type implements `System.IEquatable<R>` and includes a synthesized strongly-typed overload of `book Equals(R? other)` where R is the record type. The method is public, and the method is virtual unless the record type is sealed. *The [`Equals(R?)`] method can be declared explicitly.* It is an error if the explicit declaration does not match the expected signature or accessibility, or the explicit declaration doesn't allow overriding it in a derived type and the record type is not sealed.
> If `Equals(R? other)` is user-defined (not synthesized) but `GetHashCode` is not [user-defined], a warning is produced.

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct because indeed that way I managed to implement what I wanted. My only remaining question is if you look in my repo: https://github.com/panosru/JustDemo/tree/master/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS9Working in the `FullNameVo` record here: https://github.com/panosru/JustDemo/blob/master/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS9Working/FullNameVo.cs I have to put `public bool Equals(FullNameVo? other) => base.Equals(other);` in order for it to work, is there a way to avoid doing that and just inherit the `Equals` method from `public abstract record ValueObject`? Thanks!

Comment: I think my question in the previous comment is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64094373/c-sharp-9-0-records-tostring-not-inherited

Comment: Doesn’t look like it: “[The default synthesized Equals returns true if .. and] *there is a **base record type***, the value of base.Equals(other) (a non-virtual call to public virtual bool Equals(Base? other)); ..” — note that if the base *was* a base record type, such as one manually created: `record Foo : record ValueObjectShim : ValueObject`

Comment: could you please explain it a bit simpler? Since I have created an `abstract record ValueObject` where I define `Equals` method, and then I create `sealed record FullNameVo : ValueObject`, shouldn't the `FullNameVo` record inherit the `Equals` method of the `ValueObject` abstract record? Instead, if I don't place `public bool Equals(FullNameVo? other) => base.Equals(other);` in `FullNameVo`, then it ignores the one implemented in `ValueObject` abstract record, from which `FullNameVo` is derived.

Comment: but I'm not inhering from class, I'm inheriting from a record type: https://github.com/panosru/JustDemo/blob/b67ec8e4768f9d06c3ea874c7e15413762e9644c/ValueObjects/ValueObjectsCS9Working/ValueObject.cs#L7

Comment: Arg. So many ObjectValue implementations! Then it should call a base Equals by default, although *only does so in a combination*. This is shown in the synthesized examples. To perform the logic in the base type (only), proxy the Equals(R?) method.

Comment: yes, I added a few examples... but based on logic, I agree with you, that is what I'm arguing about, although based on this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64094532/395187 it shouldn't use the base Equals... which is very annoying tbh... Should I open a new issue about that matter?

Comment: You can check a very simple example of overriding the `ToString` method in a base class and how a class behaves in contrast with records. https://shorturl.at/abtw3

Comment: Hmm, why is my compiler complaining when I try to write GetHashCode _without_ the override keyword? Strangely, it seems that GetHashCode has to be inherited/overridden whereas Equals will be synthesized/called.

Comment: @BrunoBrant because when the compiler sees your hashcode override it doesn't provide an override, but the compiler always overrides object's Equals with a fixed implementation, which ends up either calling your type-specific Equals (because it sees you provided one and it doesn't) or the type-specific Equals it synthesizes

Answer (score 2):

I found the accepted answer hard to understand; perhaps this is simpler:

Records are classes; when you write `record` the compiler writes a class. This is no different to when you write a class; if you omit the constructor, the compiler writes one etc, so in the background the compiler is writing a lot of code for you, which makes your code less cluttered but means C# still works in the ways it originally did

When you make a record that doesn't inherit anything:

```
    record MyRecord(string MyString, int MyInt);
```

the compiler generates two `Equals` methods for you.

The first is:

```
    virtual bool Equals(MyRecord other) {
      //complicated comparison of properties etc here
    }
```

..and this one is quite an involved one that performs an Equals check on all public members, verifying that `this.MyString.Equals(other.MyString) && this.MyInt.Equals(other.MyInt) && ...` and so on

The second is:

```
    override bool Equals(object other) {
        return this.Equals(other as MyRecord); //call the first one
    }
```

..and as per above, all this one does is call the first one with a cast. If `as` is casting an object that is not a MyRecord, then the first Equals is called with a `null`, and that situation is handled

---

You can't provide your own version that `override`'s Object's `Equals(object other)` because when the compiler generates the same thing you end up with an "already defines member..." error, so you have to leave the compiler to generate that one

However, you don't need to override object's Equals, because if you provide your own custom `virtual Equals(MyRecord other)` the compiler won't generate its version, and all the other things that might call `Equals(object)` will get redirected to your custom `Equals(MyRecord)` anyway, via the override the compiler creates that now calls your custom `Equals(MyRecord)`

Your `Equals(MyRecord)` is `virtual` so it can be overridden again if inherited.

When you inherit a record, and don't provide a custom Equals, the compiler generates three `Equals` methods:

```
  virtual bool Equals(MySubRecord other)       //performs actual check
  override bool Equals(object other)           //from object, calls the first one
  sealed override bool Equals(MyRecord other)  //from parent, this calls the second one
```

If your custom method wasn't virtual, and you subclassed MyRecord into MySubRecord, the compiler will still want to provide its own `virtual bool Equals(MySubRecord other)` in the derived class. As yours isn't virtual this causes a compiler error because the virtual method the compiler creates implicitly overrides your custom method in the parent. In essence, because the compiler can only do one of two things:

- write its own version in that templated, scripted way it always does
- see that you wrote your own version, and not write anything

it means that anything you create has to fit into the way it arranges all the things it writes for you, and that means following a particular format

Comment: Note: I've omitted nullable reference type syntax for simplicity but if nullable was enabled your custom methods would look like `Equals(MyRecord? other`