# How to make records equality case-insensitive for strings?

Tags: c#, string, equality, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

I really like the C# 9 records. However, I can't find an elegant and concise way to accomplish somethink like this:

```
record MyKey(string Foo, int Bar);

[Fact]
public void ShouldEqualIgnoreCase()
{
    MyKey a = new("ID", 42);
    MyKey b = new("Id", 42);

    Assert.Equal(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Equality check for C# 9 records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326511/custom-equality-check-for-c-sharp-9-records)

Comment: You could apply `.ToUpper()` to both strings before checking equality.

Comment: @FelixCastor I wan't to preserve the casing of the strings, so I cannot apply `.ToUpper()` before assigning them to the record.

Comment: @Eldar your link is helpful, thanks. However I'm not really satisfied with the result, having to implement Equals (and GetHashCode) myself again. Hence looking for a nice solution (maybe there is none).

Comment: As for the duplicate vote, don't know if it makes a difference to the other question, but I do only care about case-insensitivity and no further logic or exceptions.

Comment: @DavWEB You have to implement the comparison and/or equality to make it case-insensitive, otherwise there is no workaround, no built-in functionality for such a thing, and there never will be, as I know, and as for any type, class, struct or record. Additional note: except the @.JonasH's proposal below, which displaces the problem.

Comment: Have you considered making a "CaseInsensitiveString"-type? That could let you override the equality comparison in one place instead of every record.

Comment: If it would be somehow possible to exclude certain properties from equality comparison, this would help. I could add `Foo` and `FooAsUpper` ignoring the `Foo` property in the comparison.

Comment: `Assert.True(a.Foo.Equals(b.Foo, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));` you can do like this

Answer (score 2):

Just use ValueObjects instead of primitives. Just as JonasH already said.

Make a new class named "CaseInsensitiveString" that implements IEquatable. The record will then use the Equals method.

Something like this:

```
    public readonly struct CaseInsensitiveString : IEquatable<CaseInsensitiveString>
    {
        public readonly String StringValue;

        public CaseInsensitiveString( string value )
        {
            StringValue = value;
        }

        public bool Equals( CaseInsensitiveString other)
        {
            return string.Equals( StringValue, other.StringValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase );
        }

        public static implicit operator string( CaseInsensitiveString h ) => h.StringValue;
        public static implicit operator CaseInsensitiveString( string s ) => new CaseInsensitiveString(s);
    }
```

Because of the implicit operators you can just use strings:

```
record MyKey(CaseInsensitiveString Foo, int Bar);
...
var a = new MyKey("ID", 42 );
```

See also: [https://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession`](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession%60)

Comment: The C2 articles on `ValueObject` are just Java people re-inventing (if not re-discovering...) [refinement-types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_type) from FP... - Anyway, in my experience I find that refinement-types  should be `readonly struct` to minimize their overhead (as they don't/shouldn't have any mutable state of their own). In C# 11 we can now use `readonly record struct` too.