# Is there a C# attribute on a record field to exclude a field from comparison?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I am getting data with an updated timestamp that I would like to ignore for example:

```
public record Person
{
    public string LastName,
    public string FirstName,
    public string MiddleName,
    [isThereAnAttributeThatICanPutHere]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt
}
```

C# `record`s auto generates code that compares records by value, and I would like to take advantage of that feature but need to exclude one field. I know that I can provide my own `GetHashCode` but that would defeat the purpose of trying to stay simple. I also know that I can compare with the following:

`person1 with {UpdateAt = null} == person2 with {UpdateAt = null}` // this will need UpdatedAt to be nullable

but that looks like needless allocations.

Comment: You seem to know that you [can make your own equality logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326511/custom-equality-check-for-c-sharp-9-records), what brought you on to using attributes? Total shot in the dark?

Comment: @gunr2171 Too many fields to compare in my case, I'm looking for a shortcut - a way that it is all generated on its own.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but for the benefit of anyone else who has the same question, I find that a simple, low-overheard approach this this is to compare using nondestructive mutation to equalize the properties that we want ignored. e.g.:

var result = 
instance1 with { UpdatedAt = DateTime.MinValue }
== instance2 with { UpdatedAt = DateTime.MinValue };

An extension method could be used to make this more succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at the moment there is nothing build in, so unless you are willing to write your own custom implementation (potentially using source generators) you are limited to manual overriding of the `Equals` (and `GetHashCode` JIC). Something similar was discussed for `PrintMembers` in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3925#issuecomment-696268613) and it seems that attribute approach is not considered by the .NET team.